# How to call a find employee function whenever a conference is created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-twiml

A js code to create a conference whenever a user calls. But it's missing a part, how to call find_employee function (calls various employees and joins them to a conference)

```js
const OVERNIGHT_IVR_INPUT_HANDLER_FUNCTION_NAME = '/overnight-vp/ivr-handler'

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {

  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  twiml.say('Please wait while we connect you to the emergency system.');

  const dial = twiml.dial();

  dial.conference('test-conference', {

    startConferenceOnEnter: false,

    record: 'record-from-start',

    waitUrl: '<url>',

  });

  callback(null, twiml);


};
```

Looked around twiml docs of `<Conference>` but there is no parameter to call a url on creating the conference.

Comment: Can you please explain what you've tried so far and where you are stuck now?  I'm not sure if I understand what you try to achieve and what is not working but I'd recommend having a look at the [Conference Participant Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource). That describes how to add (and remove) participants to a conference.

Comment: I was trying to call an employee, and if he answers add him to conference. Figured out the way, create twilio client and the call the employee with the client with url pointing to XML that says join conference.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I'm still not sure what the actual problem / error is. Conferences get created on the fly when the first participant joins.

Comment: The main problem was, how do I call and add another participant to the conference. It's solved gonna write an answer later.